# Find real solutions for a mod equation with power

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve this equation and find all real values of $x$ -

$$|x-3|^{3x^2-10x+3}=1$$

Comment: Hi. Can you show a bit of your work on this so far? This way it is generally easier to help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve $3x^2-10x+3=0$, and make sure that none of the solutions is $3$ (in order to avoid $0^0$):

- $x_1=\frac{10+\sqrt{100-36}}{6}=3$
- $x_2=\frac{10-\sqrt{100-36}}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$

Now solve $|x-3|=1$:

- $x_1=2$
- $x_2=4$

Ruling out $x=3$, we are left with $x=\frac{1}{3},2,4$.

Comment: Bingo.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user2414789: You're welcome :)

Comment: @barakmanos. I think that $3$ is also a solution of the problem.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: $0^0$ is undefined.

Comment: @barakmanos. I suppose that this is the point where you do not agree. The limit of $x^x$ when $x$ goes to $0$ is $1$ (at least to me). Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: Why don't you check the equation above in Wolfram then?

Comment: @barakmanos. I checked it using another CAS.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: The limit works well, but the equation $x^x$ at $x=0$ is still undefined.

Comment: If $g(x)=|x-3|^{3x^2-10x+3}-1$,$g(2.99999)=0.000921455$ and $g(3.00001)=-0.000920613$

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: And $g(3)=$?

Comment: @barakmanos.g(3)=0

Answer (score 3):

$$a^m=1\implies$$

either $a=1$

or ( $m=0$ and $a\ne0$)

or ( $a=-1$ and $m$ is even )

Comment: You should add to the second line: "and $a \neq 0$".

Comment: @barakmanos, thanks for pointing out

Comment: You're welcome :) Now, can you please explain @Claude Leibovici (commenting my answer), why $0^0$ is undefined?

Comment: I just wanted to know is there a way to solve the third condition ?

Comment: @user2414789: In you case there isn't, because of the `abs`.

Comment: @barakmanos, $$0^0=\frac00$$  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#Indeterminate_form_00

Comment: Well, it's not equal to $1$, is it? I'm having a hard time explaining that to @Claude Leibovici. Am I wrong here?