# What is the solution to the equation $9^x - 6^x - 2\cdot 4^x = 0 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, roots, exponentiation

I want to solve: $$9^x - 6^x - 2\cdot 4^x = 0 $$

I was able to get to the equation below by substituting $a$ for $3^x$ and $b$ for $2^x$:

$$ a^2 - ab - 2b^2 = 0 $$

And then I tried

\begin{align}x &= \log_3{a} \\
x &= \log_2{b} \\
\log_3{a} &=\log_2{b}\end{align}
But I don't know what to do after this point. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384090/find-all-real-numbers-x-for-which-frac8x27x12x18x-frac76

Comment: good question for test our knoweledge

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT:

Divide by $4^x$  to get $$a^2-a-2=0$$  where $a=\left(\dfrac32\right)^x$

Can you solve for $a?$

Now for real $x,a>0$

**See also** : [Exponent Combination Laws](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws)

Comment: Thanks so much. But how do I see intuitively what to divide / substitute in these cases? Does it happen over time?

Comment: @MertcanEkiz, Probably yes. See also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788757/find-real-solutions-for-a-mod-equation-with-power/788763#788763

Comment: @MertcanEkiz:  You had the "hint" when you were able to reformulate the equation which involved $x$ as the only unknown (appearing as an exponent) into the quadratic in two unknowns $a,b$.  This was "homogeneous in degree", which means that the approach of dividing through by $b^2$ gets you back to an equation in one unknown, namely $a/b$ (in the notation of your Question).  That's the equation that lab starts from.

Answer (score 5):

The more elegant way to solve this equation was given by lab bhattacharjee, but I'll simply elaborate on how to solve it using your method, which was still correct.

**Hint:** We have that $$a^2 - ab -2b^2 = 0 \iff b = \frac{a}{2}, \text{or }b= -a.$$

---

You now have a system of two equations, $\log_3 a = \log_2 b$ and from this you can see that neither $a$ or $b$ can be negative. So you need to rule out $b=-a$ as a solution. Instead, we take $b= a/2$. Substituting this into the logarithmic equation gives $$\log_3 a = \log_2 \frac{a}{2} \implies \large a = 2^{\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 3/2}}$$

Then $$x = \log_3 a = \frac{\ln 3}{\ln 3/2} \log_3 2 = \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3/2} = \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3 - \ln 2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Can you factorise the quadratic?

Comment: This is  more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @hardmath It is a hint in response to "I don't know what to do ... Any help is appreciated." To give more substance - if you are able to reduce to a quadratic expression, factorising is always worth considering since it reduces one quadratic to two linear. In other cases completing the square is worth testing.

Answer (score 0):

It is a homogeneous quadratic polynomial in two variables. The first thing to do is to de-homogenise it:
$$a^2-ab-2b^2=b^2\biggl(\frac{a^2}{b^2}-\frac ab-2\biggr)$$
So setting $t=\dfrac ab$, you have to solve $\;t^2-t-2=0$, which has $-1$ as a root, hence the other is $2$, en the relation between $a$ and $b$ is:
$$a=-b\quad\text{or}\quad a=2b$$
As $x$ is a real number, the first solution can't happen. So we have:
$$3^x=2^{x+1}\iff 2=x\ln 3=(x+1)\ln2\iff x=\frac{\ln2}{\ln 3-\ln 2}.$$