# How can I solve $5^{2x} + 4(5^x) - 5 = 0$?

Tags: logarithms

This is a math problem I'm currently working on.

$$5^{2x} + 4(5^x) - 5 = 0$$

I've used logarithm to try solve the problem. Here's what I've done so far:

\begin{align}5^{2x} + 4(5^x) - 5 &= 0\\
5^{2x} + 5^x &= \frac{5}{4}\\
\log_5{2x} + \log_5{x} &= \log_5\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)\\
\log_5{2x^2} &= \log_5\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)\\
5^{2x^2} &= 5^\frac{5}{4}\\
(2x^2)\log5 &= \frac{5}{4}\log5\\
2x^2 &= \frac{5}{4}\\
2x^2 &= 1.25\\
x^2 &= 0.625\\
\sqrt {x^2} &= \sqrt {0.625}\\
x &= \frac{\sqrt {10}}{4}\end{align}

Substituting the value for $x$ into the equation doesn't equate it to zero. I've tried several different ways but I have still not come up with a correct answer.

Comment: As it is currently written, the solution cannot be expressed in term of standard functions.

Comment: @AugieJavax98 -- Log of a sum is not the sum of the logs.

Comment: If it is $(5^{x})^2+4(5^x)-5=0$ then one may set $X=5^x$...

Comment: Write $5^x=y\implies5^{2x}=(5^x)^2=(y)^2$ See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356236/what-is-the-solution-to-the-equation-9x-6x-2-cdot-4x-0

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

A useful trick is to substitute $u=5^x$ to obtain a quadratic equation:

$$u^2+4u-5=0$$
Can you solve for $u$, and then solve for $x$?

Comment: Ok. I'll try and do that

Answer (score 3):

You made a pretty big mistake because $\log a + \log b \neq \log (a+b)$. So, your third line does not follow from your second.

To actually solve the problem, here's two hints:

- Set $y=5^x$
- Use the fact that $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$

Answer (score 2):

$\require{enclose}5^{2x}+4(5)^{x}-5=0 \enclose{updiagonalstrike}{\implies} 5^{2x}+5^{x}=\frac{5}{4}$

Instead:

Let $y=5^x\quad$ noting that $y\geq 0$, then we have:

$y^2+4y-5=0\implies (y+5)(y-1)=0$

$\implies y=-5\quad\text{reject since}\quad y\geq 0\quad \text{or}\quad y=1\implies 5^x=1\implies x=0$

Comment: Thanks for that :) I already worked it out using the the previous hints