# $\frac{25^x+125}{6}=5^{x+1}$ what is the value of $x$?

Tags: exponentiation

**I**t is just the title, $$\frac{25^x+125}{6}=5^{x+1}$$ What is the value of $x$?

Thanks.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356236/what-is-the-solution-to-the-equation-9x-6x-2-cdot-4x-0

Comment: Hint: $\,25^x=5^{2x}=\left(5^x\right)^2\,$.

Comment: Yes, it's a quadratic equation in disguise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$25^x+125 = 6(5^{x+1})$$

$$5^{2x}-30(5^x)+125=0$$

Quadratic equation might be helpful.

Comment: But how to eliminate 30? 125 is equal to $5^3$

Comment: I can replace $5^x$ for an $m$.

Comment: Then you get: $m^2-30m+125=0$.

Comment: So (m-25)(m-5)=0.  So m=25 or m=5.  So $5^x = 25$ or $5^x=5$.  Those are solvable aren't they.