# Solving $4\cdot 25^x-25\cdot 4^{x+1}=9\cdot 10^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, quadratics

> Solve the following equation:$$4\cdot 25^x-25\cdot 4^{x+1}=9\cdot 10^x.$$

We can decompose it to

$$2^2\cdot 5^{2x}-5^2\cdot 2^{2(x+1)}=3^2\cdot 10^x$$

$$2^2\cdot 5^{2x}-5^2\cdot 2^{2}\cdot 2^{2x}=3^2\cdot 10^x$$

How can we continue from here?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356236/what-is-the-solution-to-the-equation-9x-6x-2-cdot-4x-0?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $10^x = 2^x\cdot 5^x$. Divide by $2^{2x}$ on both sides, and you now have a quadratic equation in the unknown $(5/2)^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^x=t$.

Hence, $$4t^2-100=9t$$ or
$$\left(2t-\frac{9}{4}\right)^2=100+\frac{81}{16}$$ or
$$\left(2t-\frac{9}{4}\right)^2=\left(\frac{41}{4}\right)^2,$$
which gives $t=\frac{25}{4}$ and $x=2$.